# CTRL+D (EOF) not detected in trivial program with getchar()?

Tags: c

I have the following piece of c code. When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the program does not recognize it as EOF.

Few notes:

> I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on a VMware player
>   Using gcc and running the program from command line
>   The 'stty -a' shows eof = ^D

thanks for any help..

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 int main()
  4 {
  5    int c, nl;
  6    nl = 0;
  7    while ((c != getchar()) != EOF)
  8    {
  9       if (c == '\n')
 10          ++nl;
 11    }
 12    printf("line: %d\n", nl);
 13 
 14    return 0;
 15 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
 while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Otherwise you are comparing the result of `(c != getchar())` to `EOF`.

Answer (score 5):

```
while ((c != getchar()) != EOF)
```

This compares the value of the `int` variable `c` (which you haven't initialized) for *inequality* to the value returned by `getchar()`.  This comparison yields 0 or 1, which cannot be equal to `EOF`, which is negative.

You want to replace the `!=` (inequality comparison) by `=` (assignment).

Answer (score 3):

`while ((c != getchar()) != EOF)`

should be

`while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`